# redis cluster give client 127.0.0.1 ip

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

and after cluster started. each node show's it's ip:port as 127.0.0.1:3000x

and the client is on another machine. certainly can't reach 127.0.0.1:3000x

is there any configuration to ask the redis nodes use a subnet ip instead of 127.0.0.1?

I didn't found any host configuration in config.

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 1
>>> 'host 10.1.130.193'
```

I found **bind** directive. and used it. each node tells me that `IP address for this node updated to 10.1.130.193`. 
problem solved.

Answer (score -3):

just use **bind** instead of host.